Spectral Irradiation Plots: Units/ Order of Magnitude
I am hoping to get unconfused about calculations of irradiation vs the many plots I have found online for calculated spectral irradiance from the sun assuming it is a Black Body. I have found that my calculations are 4 orders of magnitude different than say, the plots shown here:

Using Planck's black body equation, I get a peak irradiance at 493 nm (assumed temp of 5873 K) of 2.862 x 10^4 W/(m^2-nm). Oddly enough, this is equivalent to a different plot from the same site (2.5 x 10^7 W/(m^2-um) which is the same as to 2.5 x 10^4 W/(m^2-nm):

Reference for plots: https://www.e-education.psu.edu/meteo300/node/686 (But they are elsewhere on the interwebs too)

The reason for the discrepancy is that the second plot shows the power emitted by the Sun, and the first plot shows the power received at Earth.
Also, the linked site says that the second plot is of the spectral irradiance, but it is actually a plot of the spectral radiance (it is the spectral power emitted per area per solid angle - the proper unit is $\mathrm{W}\,\mathrm{m}^{-2}\,\mathrm{\mu m}^{-1}\,\mathrm{sr}^{-1}$). Although the site says the plot is given by equation 6.4, you will find it is actually off by a factor of $\pi$.

Thank you! Your answer is very helpful.
